# Vue3 i18n hydration issue on SSR & dynamic locale change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, quasar-framework, vue-i18n

In a Quasar (vue3 composition api vue-i18n server side rendering) app I want to change the locale definition dynamically by url param. For this I've configured my router to have a `:locale?` prefix for all routes and I also created a router `beforeEnter` callback to handle changing the locale:

**router/routes.ts**

```
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/:locale?',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    beforeEnter: routerTranslator.routeMiddleware,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') },
      { path: 'sys_config', component: () => import('pages/SysConfig.vue')},
      { path: 'register', component: () => import('pages/NewRegistrationPage.vue')}
    ],
  },
```

**i18/index.ts**

```
export const routerTranslator = {
  async routeMiddleware(to, _from, next) {
    let paramLocale = to.params.locale

    if (!paramLocale) {
      paramLocale = 'en-US'
    }
    globalI18n.global.locale.value = paramLocale
    return next()
  },
}
```

So when I visit, for example, `localhost:8080/pt/register` it indeed recognizes the `:locale?` param from the url and it successfully changes the app's global i18n configuration so my components starts getting translated copies from my `pt` messages but when I look at the browser's console I see a warning like this:

> [Vue warn]: Hydration text content mismatch in :
>
> - Client: Insert a valid number that you owns. It will be verified.
> - Server: Insira um número válido e de sua propriedade. O número será verificado.

and an error like this:

> Hydration completed but contains mismatches.

It seems like it's being translated server side but client side it was expecting the original copy? How can I solve this? Any help appreciated. Thanks